# Display li elements inline with correct automatic height

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to customize [this theme](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin-v2/). (scroll down on the dashboard to see the timeline example) I'm trying to make the timeline shift up a little (to fill the gap on the empty side). I tried making `timeline > li:before` and after to use `display: inline-table` however each element still takes a whole row with incorrect height set rendering buttons on the bottom of the panel useless. 
Can you suggest me a starting point on how I can automatically set the correct height and allow them to be more compact?

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle to the question with relative code?

Comment: What is the empty side? Opposite to each panel (left part if panel on right, for example)? With panels on alternate sides, how would the 3rd panel know about the height of the 1st one above?

Comment: ^ Thats exactly what I don't know. A better solution would be to set every two panels opposite each other. This way badges will be messed up. I can't figure how they are being placed on the exact correct spot. I tried adding jsfiddle but there is a lot of css. I'll try to make one now

Comment: Like having one row and 2 panels with badges at 25 and 75% of the height of a row? That'd be a good visual solution, more compact, that'd involve rewriting part of this component (completely feasible though) but one drawback would be the semantics: 16 events in 8 list items isn't a proper use of a list :/

Comment: I've been asked to make it a lot more compact so I think it should work. which parts do I have to rewrite in order to achieve that?

Comment: The HTML code is going to be different: you'd need to distinguish between L and R event in each row so there's a need for new classes. Then it's up to you to adapt this component to your needs, see what's OK and reusable, what needs slight adjustments, what must be added or rewritten from scratch. Nobody here is going to do that first part for you

Comment: Ok thanks I'll get on with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a little space, but not much by adding these two lines to the stylesheet:

```
.timeline > li:not(:first-child) > .timeline-panel {
    top: -50px;
}


.timeline > li:not(:first-child) > .timeline-badge {
    top: -35px;
}
```

This, however affected all the timeline badges and panels except for the first one, which is good. But the overlap you require won't be seen except on the second child. After that the behavior is the same: all the timeline elements have empty space on the opposite side of the timeline.

It's going to be tough with the `display: table` on the `li` element. If you were using a CSS processor like SASS you could try a mixin and hack something together like this:

```
@mixin timeline-badge($index) {
    top: ($index * -35);
}

@mixin timeline-panel($index) {
    top: ($index * -35) - 15;
}

.timeline > li:nth-child(1) > .timeline-panel {
    @include timeline-panel(1);
}

.timeline > li:nth-child(2) > .timeline-panel {
    @include timeline-panel(2);
}

// repeat for nth-child 3-???

.timeline > li:nth-child(1) > .timeline-badge {
    @include timeline-badge(1);
}

.timeline > li:nth-child(2) > .timeline-badge {
    @include timeline-badge(2);
}

// repeat for nth-child 3-???
```

Of course, if you expect something like 50 timeline elements you're going to have a lot of extra lines in your .scss file.